# AngularJS expressions in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm using AngularJS' expressions as attribute values in .xsl templates, like this:

```
<div attribute="{{angularjs.expression}}" data-stuff="{./someId}">
```

But XSLT takes notice of the curly brackets and tries to process the expression. How can I escape the double curly brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to duplicate them: `attribute="{{{{angularjs.expression}}}}"`.

Comment: can you show a simple example of integration xslt and angular?